# Possible complement of $L =\{a^n b^{n+1} : n\geq0 \}$

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

The language was $L =\{a^n b^{n+1} : n\geq0 \}$.

This is my attempt: 
I believed $L$ can also be expressed as: 
$L =\{a^n b^{n}b : n\geq0 \}$ 
This implies that the number of $b$'s is always greater than the number of $a$'s. Thus, the complement is
$L' =\{w: w\in\{a,b\}^*: n_a(w)>n_b(w)\}$ or $L' =\{w: w\in\{a,b\}^*: n_a(w)\geq n_b(w)\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Once we've fixed the alphabet, the complement is simply the set of all strings over that alphabet that don't have the form $a^nb^{n+1}$. Presumably, here, the alphabet is $\{a,b\}$.  Again, once the alphabet is fixed, there is only one complement.  You've given two and it's unclear whether you mean "I'm not sure which of these answers is right" or "It's the set of all strings that are either like this or like that."

In fact, neither of your two answers is correct. The complement also includes the string $abbb$, even though it has more $b$s than $a$s.

Comment: Yes I'm not sure if there is only one complement of this language. But I don't think only strings that are bunch of a's followed by a bunch of b's count, since I given the example where number of a's in a string is greater than number of b's which doesn't necessarily means bunch of a's followed by bunch of b's.

Comment: @tramyardg Doh, so I was the one who'd got railroaded into thinking that everything is a bunch of $a$s followed by a bunch of $b$s! I've deleted that part of my answer. But there's always only one complement. There might be more than one condition that tells you that something is in the complement, but there's only one complement.